# Is azure data factory ELT?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a question about Azure Data Factory (ADF).  I have read (and heard) contradictory info about ADF being ETL or ELT.  So, is ADF ETL?  Or, is it ETL?  To my knowledge, ELT uses the transformation (compute?) engine of the target (whereas ETL uses a dedicated transformation engine).  To my knowledge, ADF uses Databricks under the hood, which is really just an on-demand Spark cluster.  That Spark cluster is separate from the target.  So, that would mean that ADF is ETL.  But, I'm not confident about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

It all depends on what you use and how you use it.

If it is strictly a copy activity, then it is ELT.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview

The transform can be a stored procedure (does not matter RDBMS) and the source/destination are tables.  If the landing zone is a data lake, then you want to call a Databricks or Synapse notebook.  Again, the source is a file.  The target is probably a delta table.  Most people love SQL and delta tables give you those ACID properties.

Now, if you using a mapping or wrangling data flow, then it is ETL, if the pattern is pure.  Of course you can mix and match. Both these data flows use a spark engine.  It cost money to have big spark clusters running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/wrangling-tutorial

Here is an article from MSDN.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/relational-data/etl

It has old (SSIS) and new (SYNAPSE) technologies.